# System.Text.Json packages adds System.ValueTuple package even though it shouldnt need it

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

So this is pretty easy to reproduce. Create a .Net Framework 4.7.2 project and add System.Text.Json nuget package (v 5.0.2), see that it says it's going to add dependent packages including System.ValueTuple.

[image: List of dependencies when installing System.Text.Json]

But from what I understand it shouldn't.

.Net Framework 4.7.2 is .Net Standard 2.0 (see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) and includes System.ValueTuple within the BCL.

We can see on the nuget website for System.Text.Json https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json that for .net standard 2.0 System.ValueTuple is not a dependency

[image: Dependencies listed on Nuget.org for System.Text.Json]

but it is for framework 4.6.1

So here is the big question... why is nuget resolving the dependencies for 4.6.1 when my project targets 4.7.2 which is .Net Standard 2.0??

Comment: According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/8896): *"If a library is netstandard only, net472 will pick that. If a library has any net framework targets, net472 will pick that instead."* So this is the expected, if not particularly obvious, behaviour.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Thank you! Obviously solving the problem would be the best outcome, but actually understanding it is a close second. I really struggled to find info on this, so I really appreciate you sharing the link. I would consider your comment worthy of an answer and that way I can give you some of those sweet internet points that we all crave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/8896): *"If a library is netstandard only, net472 will pick that. If a library has any net framework targets, net472 will pick that instead."*

So this is the expected, if not particularly obvious, behaviour.

Fortunately, the `System.ValueTuple` NuGet package has a separate target for .NET 4.7 which forwards the types to the BCL implementation, so the extra reference shouldn't cause any problems.