# How to use the latest version of System.ValueTuple together with System.Text.Json in my build?

Tags: c#, system.text.json, nuget-package-restore, valuetuple

I want to use the latest version of `System.ValueTuple` which comes with .NetFramework 4.8 as far as I know. However, I have a dependency to `System.Text.Json 8.0.1` referencing an older version (>= 4.3.0) of `System.ValueTuple`. NuGet will automatically restore transitive dependencies and therefore I cannot define a never version of `System.ValueTuple` myself for NuGet restore, because it is not inside a NuGet package. It is delivered with .NetFramework 4.8. I can also not use [transitivePinning](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-central-package-management/) and CPM, because again, the latest `System.ValueTuple` is not a nuget package.

What have I tried?
I created a small console application only referencing `System.Text.Json 8.0.1` and there is indeed an old version (4.6.XX) of `System.ValueTuple` in my binary folder. I found [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69569664/7559642) stating that the old version might be referencing the new one. Can anyone verify that? I couldn't find any documentation by Microsoft confirming or denying that. I also double checked the file version of `System.ValueTuple` in my .NetFramework folder which is indeed higher (4.8.XX).

I assume there is no issue, because the method signatures probably didn't change. However, it looks a bit risky to me to build against an old version and not ship the .dll to customers.

Comment: There's no newer version. Only .NET Framework has a dependency for System.ValueTupe 4.5 or later (not 4.3), which actually the *last* version of [System.ValueTuple](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.ValueTuple/), released back in 2018. In .NET Framework 4.8 the latest version is already included in the runtime

Comment: Do you have any actual problems caused by this?

Comment: @GuruStron no, only a bad feeling, because my build is building against a .dll which is not used at customer site. I wanted to double check, that I am not missing anything.

Comment: @tomwaitforitmy _"my build is building against a .dll which is not used at customer site."_ - it's been quite some time since I have deep dived into .NET Framework version of dll hell so I can spew some nonsense here. But still. How is your dll is distrubuted? If as nuget than you should not bother, it should work correctly.

Comment: @GuruStron Msi Installer. I have to decide whether to include `System.ValueTuple.dll` or not. I don't think it should be an issue, but its weird that the build is building against a file that I am not shipping. Again: I wanted to double check that I am not missing anything.

Comment: Personally I would suggest to ship everything what was published to corresponding folder.

Comment: @GuruStron so you would ship the old System.ValueTuple even though .NetFramework 4.8 is installed at customer site?

Comment: @tomwaitforitmy you always can try first shipping without extra dlls,